# Proving that all prime powers are deficient using induction

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to prove that all prime powers are deficient by induction using $\sigma(p^n) = \frac{p^{(n+1)} - 1}{ p -1}$. I am not sure whether this is a valid approach. So far I have:

Base Case: $\sigma(p^0) = \frac{p^{(0+1)} - 1 }{ p -1} = 1 < 2p^0 = 2$

Assume: $\sigma(p^k) =\frac{ p^{k+1} - 1 }{ p -1 }< 2p^k$

Then add $p^{k+1}$ to both sides:

$\sigma(p^{k+1}) = p^{k+1} + (\frac{p^{k+1} - 1 }{ p -1}) < p^{k+1} + 2p^k$

$\sigma(p^{k+1}) = \frac{p^{k+1}(p-1)}{p-1} + (\frac{p^{k+1} - 1} {p -1}) < p^{k+1} + 2p^k$

$\sigma(p^{k+1}) =\frac{( p^{k+1}(p-1) + p^{k+1} - 1 )}{ p -1} < p^{k+1} + 2p^k$

$\sigma(p^{k+1}) =\frac{( p^{k+2} - p^{k+1} + p^{k+1} - 1 )}{ p -1 }< p^{k+1} + 2p^k$

$\sigma(p^{k+1}) =\frac{( p^{k+2} - 1 )}{ p -1} < p^{k+1} + 2p^k$

I believe that I have shown what I need to show on the left hand side, but I am having trouble getting the right hand side to simplify to $2p^{k+1}$. Is there some way to simplify the right hand side into this form?

If there is not a way to simplify the right hand side in a satisfying way, is there some argument that I can still make to prove it this way? Something along the lines of $p^{k+1} + 2p^k < 2p^{k+1}$ so $\frac{( p^{k+2} - 1 )}{ p -1 }< 2p^{k+1}$?

Thanks!

Comment: Induction doesn't seem terribly useful here...the proper divisors of $p^n$ are $1, p, \cdots, p^{n-1}$, and their sum is $1+p+\cdots p^{n-1}=\frac {p^n-1}{p-1}<p^n$.